# How to parse line by line to textfile?

Tags: java, output, line, filewriter

I was trying to read Strings line by line, and write it thru the FileWriter to a text file. The file must be overwrite, thus I can't use true as second parameter in FileWriter. Before the String reach the writeToFile method, I could use = to parse the String, however then I got just the last String line, because its overwrite. With += it gets a one line String of all the Strings. I tried also to split() the String into multiples, but it's the same. How could I change the code below, to get as output line by line ?

Thanks

```
   private void writeToFile(File cf, String ln) throws IOException {
    //true won't work as the data must be overwrite.  
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(cf);
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
         // I got just one string all at the same line. Or just the last-
         // String
         bw.write(ln);
         bw.newLine();
         bw.flush();
    }
   }
```

Comment: you could use a temporary file/string to read to and then edit it and write that string back to the file

Comment: It's possible to do it, when the file it's to be encrypted ?